# pointing domain to AWS Server causes redirect loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, hosting, web-hosting

I followed these exact steps here: http://www.holovaty.com/writing/aws-domain-redirection/

Basically, I first created an S3 bucket, added DES rules in route 53 and then gave the registrar (which I nought the domain from) amazons name servers. I started with just mmysite.com and then repeated the steps for www.mysite.com and now when I go to the site, it is giving me an error saying "This web page has a redirect loop and has resulted in too many redirects". Happens when I use www and when I don't as well. Any idea why? I followed the exact same steps mentioned in the link I provided.

Comment: Those instructions were someone trying to redirect all requests for A.com (and www.A.com) to B.com - is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: @Frederickcheng I Bought a domain, x.com.. I bought an aws server which is running right now at x.aws.amazon.elasticbeanstalk.com. I want it so that whenever someone goes to x.com, it should load the elastic beanstalk server / site but the domain should still be x.com

Comment: Those instructions are for doing something else. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html for example.

Comment: @FrederickCheung hm okay so I created a CNAME which record that maps to my amazon URL, but now it is giving me a 404 error saying "No such bucket. The specified bucket does not exist. myapp.com". Any idea why? Note: I didn't do the "Using a Domain Hosted by Amazon Route 53" part because all I need to do is create a cname record and map it to the aws URL right?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work by creating an S3 bucket which redirected to the aws url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar kind of problem. In my case I had two ec2 servers in two regions.

In both the servers I was running apache. I had included a IF condition in my

000-default.conf file. (This file is found in cd /etc/apache2/sites-available)

I had a redirect statement in this file. I removed it and it started working.